# How to fit a list of paths inside a border in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, itemscontrol, viewbox

am writing a C# WPF program to view and edit SVGs.
So i have a List of pathes (PathList) and i diplay them inside a border on a canvas here's my XAML:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathList}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>                          
                        <Canvas>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown" >
                                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path= OnMouseDownCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Canvas>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"  Height="500" Width="500">
                        <Path Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" 
                              StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
                              Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                              Data="{Binding Data}" 
                              Tag="{Binding Tag}"
                        </Viewbox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

as i said in the title my goal is to fit those paths inside a border and as you can see in my code i used Viewbox to stretch the paths but the problem is it stretches each and every path inside the list to fill the size (500*500) distorting the form of the vector graphics.. i want the scaling to happen to all the list at once as an entity leaving the relative scale and locations of those paths intact.

Comment: Did you try to put the whole ItemsControl in a Viewbox, instead of the individual items?

Comment: @Clemens yes, when i do this the svg is not displayed

Comment: You also have to set the Width and Height of the ItemsControl (or the ItemsPanel Canvas) to 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplified example shows how to put a list of Geometry items in a scalable ItemsControl. It is necessary that you set the Width and Height of the ItemsControl.

```
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl Width="500" Height="500">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Data="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="150,150" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="350,350" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: well that definitely worked but some stuff needs to be tweaked but that certainly did the trick